# Ansible template tries to calculate variables in unused branch of conditions: is this a normal behaviour?

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-template

I'm using Ansible 2.8.6 and I ran into an error with the templates when using conditions. It tries to compute some parts of the variables even when these variables are only used in "unused branches" of the templates. In my case, computing these variables does not make sense and provoke an error so I don't want Ansible to compute these variables. I expected Ansible/Jinja2 to not compute them if the condition to use them is not fulfilled.

Simple example of what I'm trying to explain:

- `pb_test.yml` (playbook)

  ```
  - name: "Testing template"
    hosts: localhost

    tasks:
      - name: "Generate a file from a template"
        template:
          src: templates/test.txt.j2
          dest: /tmp/test.txt
  ```
- `templates/test.txt.j2` (template)

  ```
  Hello, please call me:
  {% if use_last_name %}
    "{{ last_name }}". This is how my colleagues call me.
  {% else %}
    "{{ first_name }}". This is how my friends call me.
  {% endif %}
  ```
- `inventory/hosts`

  ```
  localhost
  ```
- `inventory/group_vars/all.yml`

  ```
  use_last_name: True

  names: []   ## I don't have any names in the list but it does not matter, I use last names.
  first_name: "{{ names | first }}"

  last_name: "Doe"
  ```

I would except this playbook to run fine. The variable `first_name` cannot be define but that's ok because I don't use it. Yet I have the following result:

```
$ ansible-playbook -i inventory/host -kK -u admin pb_test.yml
SSH password:
BECOME password[defaults to SSH password]:

PLAY [Testing template] ************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ****************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [Generate a file from a template] ******************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "AnsibleUndefinedVariable: No first item, sequence was empty."}

PLAY RECAP ****************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

From the error, I understand that Ansible is trying to compute `first_name` even when it will not be used. Note that if `first_name` and `names` are not defined at all, the script runs fine: as far as I can tell the problem comes from the `| first` filter that Ansible is trying to compute.

Is this a normal behaviour ? And if yes, could someone explain me why this is happening (why trying to compute a variable/filter that is not used ?). Is there a workaround to make it work like I expect it to work ?

Comment: Long story short to get you going => either define `first_name: "{{ names | first | default('') }}"` or drop that definition and use directly `"{{ names | first  }}". This is how my friends call me.` in your template. I basically know why (ansible/jinja2 "parseception"...) but don't have all the refs under my hand and the needed time to give a satisfying answer on the explanation.

Comment: jinja2 version 2.8.7

Comment: Yes I had the feeling this is linked to how ansible and jinja2 interact and parse the variables. I went for the `default()` solution which works. But I'll keep this open because I would be interested in a solution that explains (or give hints) the "behind the scene part".